# SQL Server charindex() appears to fail - does it include punctuation?

Tags: sql-server, charindex

I converted from a MySQL database to SQL Server.

In one column, I'm looking for a string:

> "status":"solved"

Note that the quotes are literally in the column.

In MySQL, I have the function ---

```
instr(child_events, '\"status\":\"solved\"')>0
```

Note that I am escaping the double quotes (all four) with a backslash. This works just as expected.

Now, I have the exact same data in SQL Server (verified).

I am performing the function:

```
charindex('\"status\":\"solved\"', child_events)>0
```

and also

```
charindex('""status"":""solved""', child_events)>0
```

This is failing. It's bringing back a handful of rows (maybe 2% of the actual with the first, 0% with the second). But then I say simply find:

> solved

Then it finds all the results.

What is going on here? Why isn't `charindex` working? The column data type is `varchar(max)` --- I had converted it from text data type initially (I'm used to MySQL) -- so maybe that didn't work. The column length can also be quite long --- possibly up to 300 or 400 characters. Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape `"` here, so the following should work:

```
charindex('"status":"solved"', child_events)>0
```

For example: [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1434)

Comment: Well don't I feel dumb now. Anyway, much appreciated.